# Serving php as css/js: Is it fast enough? What drawbacks are there?

Tags: php, javascript, css, optimization, performance

I've recently started getting into the area of optimizing preformance and load times client side, compressing css/js, gzipping, paying attention to YSlow, etc.

I'm wondering, while trying to achieve all these micro-optimizations, what are the pros and cons of serving php files as css or javascript?

I'm not entirely sure where the bottleneck is, if there is one. I would assume that between an identical css and php file, the "pure" css file would be slightly faster simply because it doesn't need to parse php code. However, in a php file you can have more control over headers which may be more important(?).

Currently I'm doing a `filemtime()` check on a "trigger" file, and with some php voodoo writing a single compressed css file from it, combined with several other files in a defined group. This creates a file like `css/groupname/301469778.css`, which the php template catches and updates the html tags with the new file name. It seemed like the safest method, but I don't really like the server cache getting filled up with junk css files after several edits. I also don't bother doing this for small "helper" css files that are only loaded for certain pages.

- If 99% of my output is generated by php anyways, what's the harm (if any) by using php to directly output css/js content? (assuming there are no php errors)
- If using php, is it a good idea to `mod_rewrite` the files to use the css/js extension for any edge cases of browser misinterpretation? Can't hurt? Not needed?
- Are there any separate guidelines/methods for css and javascript? I would assume that they would be equal.
- Which is faster: A single css file with several `@imports`, or a php file with several `readfile()` calls?
- What other ways does using php affect speed?
- Once the file is cached in the browser, does it make a difference anymore?

I would prefer to use php with .htaccess because it is much simpler, but in the end I will use whatever method is best.

Comment: I am curious why you need common headers in CSS or JavaScript files. I seldom see CSS/JS files needing modifications when served to the client. Most of PHP I see used on HTML files, even for certain id's or config variables used by your JavaScript code is usually inserted into the HTML files instead of touching the JavaScript files.

Comment: Unless you are only adding headers, mucking with JS files will prevent you from minifying or optimizing them using minifiers, optimizers and compilers.  For CSS, depending on the dynamic elements you need to add (that's why you need PHP), you may be preventing compacting the CSS files as well.  You're losing way more than just the overhead of using PHP.

Comment: @Stephen Chung: Putting the js/css directly in the html source means it cannot be cached separately from the html document. I was also wondering if using php to set headers like expires and last mod time by "wrapping" it in php was a good idea. I'm not clear on what you mean by "mucking with files prevents you from minifying them". If I send the file's output to the minifier it should not make a difference.

Comment: @Madmartigan, I am not suggesting merging CSS/JS into your HTML.  I am just remarking that there really is no need for you to use PHP with CSS/JS files.  if you are looking into setting expiry dates etc. for them, there should be simpler ways to do that in your web server.

Comment: @Stephen Chung: While I agree that there is no **need**, there certainly are many benefits to using php for css/js. My question is whether or not there are any drawbacks, what they are, and if it should be avoided or only used situationally.

Comment: @Madmartigan, well one pitfall I can see is that, every time you change your JS or CSS file, you need to run minifiers on it, and then add back in your PHP code.  It is an extra step, but not much of a bad thing, I admit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, so here are your direct answers:

- no harm at all as long as your code is fine. The browser won't notice any difference.
- no need for mod_rewrite. the browsers usually don't care about the URL (and often not even about the MIME type).
- CSS files are usually smaller and often one file is enough, so no need to combine. Be aware that combining files from different directories affect images referenced in the CSS as they remain relative to the CSS URL
- definitely readfile() will be faster as @import requires multiple HTTP requests and you want to reduce as much as possible
- when comparing a single HTTP request, PHP may be slightly slower. But you loose the possibility to combine files unless you do that offline.
- no, but browser caches are unreliable and improper web server config may cause the browser to unnecessarily re-fetch the URL.

It's impossible to give you a much more concrete answer because it depends a **lot** on your project details.

Comment: +1 Interesting about the readfile() vs @import.. it's what I expected but @simonrjones does not agree, and you sound certain. I'd be interested in reading more about this if you have any resources to share. I know I'm really splitting hairs, but that's what optimization is all about. I'd like to skip the min/combine steps for certain files/groups, but feared that using php to serve them might have a negative impact somehow. I've done it many times before, but I am not aware of every edge case. Thank you for the replies.

Comment: The only negative impact I can think of when using PHP is that it may actually be slower, but that depends on the number of files, their size and especially your PHP installation. The only way to clarify is to compare both methods in practice. Depending on your project you may also have the option to pre-combine the scripts into one static file (ie. do it offline). Anyway, it's all about speed and project management and it's up to you to weigh up the solutions.

Comment: I would like to add an update to this: if you are using HTTP2, it is not necessary or wise to prioritize reducing the number of HTTP requests. HTTP2 allows requests to occur in parallel, and combining files kind of defeats the purpose of that.

Answer (score 4):

We are developing really large DHTML/AJAX web application with about 2+ MB of JavaScript code and they still load quickly with some optimizations:

- try to reduce the *number* of Script URLs included. We use a simple PHP script that loads a bunch of .js files and sends them in one go to the browser (all concatenated). This will load your page a **lot** faster when you have a lot of .js files as we do since the overhead of setting up a HTTP connection is usually much higher that the actually transferring the content itself. Note that the browser needs to download JS files synchroneously.
- be cache friendly. Our HTML page is also generated via PHP and the URL to the scripts contains a hash that's dependent on the file modification times. The PHP script above that combines the .js files then checks the HTTP cache headers and sets a long expiration time so that the browser does not even have to load any external scripts the second time the user visits the page.
- GZIP compress the scripts. This will reduce your code by about 90%. We don't even have to minify the code (which makes debugging easier).

So, yes, using PHP to send the CSS/JS files can improve the loading time of your page a lot - especially for large pages.

EDIT: You may use this code to combine your files:

```
function combine_files($list, $mime) {

  if (!is_array($list))
    throw new Exception("Invalid list parameter");

  ob_start();

  $lastmod = filemtime(__FILE__);

  foreach ($list as $fname) {
    $fm = @filemtime($fname);

    if ($fm === false) {
      $msg = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"].": Failed to load file '$fname'";
      if ($mime == "application/x-javascript") {
        echo 'alert("'.addcslashes($msg, "\0..\37\"\\").'");';
        exit(1);
      } else {
        die("*** ERROR: $msg");
      }        
    }

    if ($fm > $lastmod)
      $lastmod = $fm;
  }

  //--

  $if_modified_since = preg_replace('/;.*$/', '', 
    $_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"]);


  $gmdate_mod = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $lastmod) . ' GMT';
  $etag = '"'.md5($gmdate_mod).'"';

  if (headers_sent())
    die("ABORTING - headers already sent");

    if (($if_modified_since == $gmdate_mod) or 
    ($etag == $_SERVER["HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH"])) {
        if (php_sapi_name()=='CGI') {
        Header("Status: 304 Not Modified");
      } else {
        Header("HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified");
      }
    exit();
    }
    header("Last-Modified: $gmdate_mod");
    header("ETag: $etag");

    fc_enable_gzip();

    // Cache-Control
    $maxage = 30*24*60*60;   // 30 Tage (Versions-Unterstützung im HTML Code!)

    $expire = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $maxage) . ' GMT';
    header("Expires: $expire");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=$maxage, must-revalidate");

  header("Content-Type: $mime");

  echo "/* ".date("r")." */\n";
  foreach ($list as $fname) {
    echo "\n\n/***** $fname *****/\n\n";
    readfile($fname);
  }
}


function files_hash($list, $basedir="") {
  $temp = array();
  $incomplete = false;

  if (!is_array($list))
    $list = array($list);

  if ($basedir!="")
    $basedir="$basedir/";

  foreach ($list as $fname) {
    $t = @filemtime($basedir.$fname);
    if ($t===false)
      $incomplete = true;
    else
      $temp[] = $t;
  }

  if (!count($temp))
    return "ERROR";

  return md5(implode(",",$temp)) . ($incomplete ? "-INCOMPLETE" : "");
}


function fc_compress_output_gzip($output) {
  $compressed = gzencode($output);

  $olen = strlen($output);
  $clen = strlen($compressed);

  if ($olen)
    header("X-Compression-Info: original $olen bytes, gzipped $clen bytes ".
      '('.round(100/$olen*$clen).'%)'); 

  return $compressed;
}
function fc_compress_output_deflate($output) {

  $compressed = gzdeflate($output, 9);

  $olen = strlen($output);
  $clen = strlen($compressed);

  if ($olen)
    header("X-Compression-Info: original $olen bytes, deflated $clen bytes ".
      '('.round(100/$olen*$clen).'%)'); 

  return $compressed;

}

function fc_enable_gzip() {
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']))
    $AE = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'];
   else
    $AE = $_SERVER['HTTP_TE'];
  $support_gzip = !(strpos($AE, 'gzip')===FALSE);
  $support_deflate = !(strpos($AE, 'deflate')===FALSE);
  if($support_gzip && $support_deflate) {
    $support_deflate = $PREFER_DEFLATE;
  }
  if ($support_deflate) {
      header("Content-Encoding: deflate");
      ob_start("fc_compress_output_deflate");
  } else{
    if($support_gzip){
      header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
      ob_start("fc_compress_output_gzip");
    } else{
      ob_start();
    }
  }
}
```

Use files_hash() to generate a unique hash string that changes whenever your source files change and combine_files() to send the combined files to the browser. So, use files_hash() when generating the HTML code for the  tag and combine_files() in the PHP script that is loaded via that tag. Just place the hash in the query string of the URL.

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="get_the_code.php?hash=<?=files_hash($list_of_js_files)?>"></script>
```

Make sure you specify the same $list in both cases.

Comment: So are you saying there are no drawbacks, only benefits? When you say you use a hash, do you mean like `style.css#v1`? Is this reliable as far as ensuring the client downloads `style.css#v2` when it becomes available? As I've commented, I've read that appending a query string is not reliable, this method seems similar. Also, I'm aware that reducing requests is a good thing, but what about speed when serving the content with php? I assume the php does not compile to css until that file is requested by the client, as the page is loading. Doesn't this affect how readily the css/js is available?

Comment: Well, it depends. Using PHP to serve a single 100-byte CSS file won't make it any faster. But serving 20 heavy .js files with just a single PHP HTTP request will make your page load within 1-2 seconds instead of 10+ seconds. 
Of course it also depends on your PHP installation, but usually PHP code is pre-compiled with some accelerator.

Comment: I added the code in my solution. I wasn't talking about URL-hash, but instead of MD5-hashes, i.e. just a string that changes when the modtime of your source files change. As part of the query string it makes the URL unique and makes sure the browser loads the most current version of the code. I can't see why that should not be reliable. 
Just try it and see with FireBug if the page loads quicker.

Comment: Thank you for the code sample, but I don't want to focus on "how to", I already have that down, as I stated in the original post. The question is about performance using php to serve css/js. I have also mentioned twice now that the query string is probably not reliable enough to force a new download on revision (which is beside the point). I'd like to hear some answers on the bullet points in my question, specifically if there are drawbacks to using php, which no one has really touched yet. Maybe the answer is "No, there are no drawbacks." Won't be faster !== Will be slower

Comment: @Madmartigan: please provide that citation about the unreliable query string method.

Comment: @Udo G: I actually had it backwards, apparently the problem is that the file may not be cached at all. [HTML5 Boilerplate intro on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=OXpCB3U_4Ig#at=322) mentions something about it at 4:30. [Another blog post](http://eric.biven.us/2008/10/09/far-future-expiration-and-file-versioning-change-the-file-name-or-add-a-query-string/) that mentions it. And then there's [this on the google page speed site](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html) (scroll to the bottom).

Comment: Ok, those are pretty rare situations (negatively affecting **performance**). Anyway: Depending on your PHP installation you may be able to use PATH_INFO. That is, your URL goes beyond the script location, like `/some/path/getstyles.php/version123`. To the browser/proxy this is a fully valid URL without query string. The server usually understands it anyway, but as said it depends on the server installation. Just try that with any PHP script on your site, by appending "/foo" to it. Then check if you get an error. Be aware that this affects relative CSS paths for the browser.

Comment: @Udo G: As I said, I already use a method that changes the actual file name to a timestamp to be on the safe side (makes a new copy of the final compressed/combined files). However I am curious: What's the point of hashing the `filemtime()` before appending it to the file name? Why is the timestamp alone not enough?

Comment: ..because we usually combine 20-30 files together and we want to consider each file timestamp instead of just the newest. The hash is just a method for reducing the query string length (instead of putting each single timestamp there).

Comment: @Udo G: Thank you for all your input! I really appreciate it, hope I didn't come off snarfy :) It's good to hear that people are doing this and I have nothing to worry about. I want to leave this open for another day or two and see if anyone else has something to share.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about serving static files via PHP, there's really little point doing that since its always going to be slower than Apache serving a normal file. A CSS @import will be quicker that PHP's readfile() but the best performance will be gained by serving one minified CSS file that combines all the CSS you need to use.

If sounds like you're on the right track though. I'd advise pre-processing your CSS and saving to disk. If you need to set special headers for things like caching just do this in your VirtualHost directive or .htaccess file.

To avoid lots of cached files you could use a simple file-naming convention for your minified CSS. For example, if your main CSS file called main.css and it references reset.css and forms.css via @imports, the minified version could be called main.min.css

When this file is regenerated it simply replaces it. If you include a reference to that file in your HTML, you could send the request to PHP if the file doesn't exist, combine and minify the file (via something like [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)), and save it to disk and therefore be served via normal HTTP for all future requests.

When you update your CSS just delete the main.min.css version and it will automatically regenerate.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The reason to update the file name itself is to ensure that users who already have the cached version of a css file download the updated one (if it exists). Since the file name changes, the browser will see it as a new file and not use the cached version.

Comment: How much quicker is `@import` than `readfile()`, just curious?

Comment: If you're worried about updates, just add a fake GET parameter to your CSS file, for example: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/reset.css?v=5" type="text/css" media="all" /> This will then force a reload and you get to keep the original filename. You'd have to do some tests with 1000s of requests to see what the exact time difference is between @import vs readfile() but generally speaking PHP will always have an overhead that static files will not have. And one combined static file will always be faster than multiple files or PHP.

Comment: The difference with @import/readfile is that the client only needs to download 1 file in the `readfile()` case, so besides initial overhead there's that to consider. I've also read many times that using a query string is not reliable enough to trigger downloading the new file. Can cite if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the preprocessing with an [ANT Build](http://www.christian-straube.de/2011/02/23/website-geschwindigkeit-verbessern/). Sorry, the post is german, but I've tried translate.google.com and it worked fine :-) So you can use the post as tutorial to achieve a better performance...
I would preprocess the files and save them to disk, just like simonrjones said. Caching-stuff etc. should be done by the dedicated elements, like Apache WebServer, Headers and Browser.

Answer (score 0):

While slower, one advantage / reason you might have to do this is to put dynamic content into the files on the server, but still have them appear to be js or css from the client perspective.

Like this for example, passing the environment from php to javascript:

```
var environment = <?=getenv('APPLICATION_ENV');?>

// More JS code here ...
```